# How to replace or look for italic text within quotation marks

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, text-editing, wildcards, citations

As a text editor, I often come across cases where the author has double marked quotations by putting them in between quotation marks and in italics. In almost all cases it is preferred to use only one of these methods.

Were the quotation marks set in italics too, it would be easy to find these instances, but unfortunately they are most often set in roman. So how can I find/replace the following cases?:

> “*Alea iacta est*,” Caesar said.

Answer (score 1):

Word's search functions do not allow us to search for a string of which only a part is formatted. The crux is thus to add an extra character to mark all italic text, and look for the sequence quotation mark + extra character.

I will be using ¡ (Upside down question mark) as extra character, as it is neither a wildcard character, is easily available on my keyboard (Ctrl + Alt + 1), and does not appear in most documents I work with. You can use any other character that suits your needs best.

1. In **Replace** (Ctrl + H), leave the *Find what* field empty, but click *Format* > *Font* > *Font style*: *Italic*.
   *Replace with*: `¡^&` (^& will repeat the *Find what* text).
   Click *Replace all*.
2. Next, *Find what*: `([\"\'“‘])¡(*)([\"\'”’])` (if you know which quotation marks are used in the document, you can also select only those) and tick *Use wildcards* (don't forget to click *No formatting*.
3. Either **Replace** with `\1\2\3` and apply no italics (*Format* > *Font* > *Font style*: *Regular*) if you want to remove the italic formatting:
   or **Replace** with `\2` if you want to remove the quotation marks;
   or **Find** and click *Reading Highlight* > *Highlight All* to highlight all cases and do with whatever you need.
4. **Replace** all cases of `¡` with nothing.