Find and Replace in between Characters in Word
I am currently formating a document which has many " " marks for spoken lines. Using find and replace, I can use the following to select everything which I wish to format.
Find: \"*\"
Replace: [My desired formatting]
However, this selects the quote marks themselves. This is not desirable for me. How can I select content in between a set of characters while ommiting the outter characters (exclusive selection is the correct name for this I assume)?

What about adding the quotes, by using "[My desired formatting]" as the replacement?

Can the Quotes be exempt from the formatting if added to the replace box? I have it empty right now.

Can you please Edit the question and add a screenshot of the replacement dialog? It may help to see the available possibilities.

I guess what you want is a Regex like this: (?<=")[^"]*(?=") that utilizes lookahead and lookbehind assertions to match content between quotation marks without including the quotes themselves. However, to perform such a replacement, you'll need a tool that supports regular expressions with lookahead and lookbehind, as Microsoft Word's built-in find and replace functionality doesn't fully support standard regex.

"you'll need a tool that supports regular expressions with lookahead and lookbehind" Do you have any suggestion?

many good text editors can do that. for example sublime text or vscode

Will it work on a Word document?

I guess it depends how many word-exclusive features are being used. AFAIK you could export to markdown, have any editor edit your file (using regexp, for example) and then import the markdown back into word.
Using regex over heavily formatted texts, or whole regions, is not something I would recommend. That's probably the reason why it doesn't exist in word - even when I'd consider it a basic feature and great help in text formatting.

https://superuser.com/questions/1621819/how-to-replace-or-look-for-italic-text-within-quotation-marks
